Where do I find alternative categorizations/groupings of English words
Not a linguist, so using Categories/Groupings might not be the correct term here. What I mean is groupings of words like all English verbs indicating movement (run, walk, stroll, fly, etc.) for example.
More Context: I am creating a fictional world with a modfified version of English. The language they use there is the exact opposite of being specific, so I want to find abstractions/groupings and invent a word for them to be used instead of the more specific one.
What would be the correct terminology for what I'm after and do you know of any source providing such lists?

Can you give more context on the purpose of this grouping? What do you want to do with it?

Try lexical categorization, explained here: https://www.happyneuronpro.com/en/the-program/lexical-categorization-exercises/#:~:text=Lexical%20categorization%20refers%20to%20the,characteristics%2C%20relationships%2C%20or%20functions.

@SirCornflakes I added some more info to the question. I hope that makes it a little less vague.

maybe look at the section headings in a thesaurus?

For constructed language, including modified English, there is also [conlang.se]. However, this does not make this question off-topic here.

It sounds like you are looking for a lexical/semantic database. WordNet is an example.

I don't know how far you want to go on abstraction, for true minimalists there is Natural Semantic Metalanguage (NSM), a framework of semantic primitives that can do a lot. An application of NSM is Minimal English (briefly described in the Wikipedia article quoted above).
You may also have a look at the constructed language (conlang) Toki Pona with a very minimalistic approach.
